# BackgroundWorker component in services

Tags: c#, windows-services

I know the BackgroundWorker should not be used in Windows Services but would anyone have a good online reference explaining why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BackgroundWorker relies on a current SynchronizationContext being set in order to function. It's really intended and designed specifically for working with UI code.

It's typically better in a service to self-manage your threads, since there are no UI synchronization issues.  Using the threading API (or .NET 4 Task API) is a much better option here.

Comment: Thank you, Reed. I had read that it should only be used for UI code, and I never use it in a service but we are having some of a "crisis" here at the office with some people claiming "it's being working for years" and that sort of thing. I wanted to give them some independent view on the matter.

Comment: In the interest of improving Otavio's ability to resolve his "crisis" - and our edification - *why* is Threading/Task API > BackgroundWorker in a service, specifically? C. Lawrence reports no ill effects: what ill effects are possible?

Comment: @djacobson: Depends on the service in question.  If there is no synchronization context in place, BW can just add some extra overhead, and provide no benefits.  If you're using it in a service with a SC, such as WCF, it will function as expected, but it's really still fairly unnecessary.  Easier to just call your DoWork method, and let it call other methods as needed...

Comment: So it sounds like it's mostly a matter of "best-fit", if I've got you. Nothing wrong with that - thanks for the elaboration. :)

Comment: @djacobson: Yes - BW just makes code in a service more complicated and slower, with no advantage.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's okayish to use a BGW in a service, it just doesn't do anything especially useful.  Its reason for being is its ability to raise the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events on a specific thread.  Getting code to run on a *specific* thread is a very non-trivial thing to do.  You cannot simply inject a call into the thread while it is executing code.  That causes horrible re-entrancy problems.  The thread has to be 'idle', in a state where inject code doesn't cause trouble.

Having a thread in an idle state is a fairly unnatural condition.  You use threads to *run* code, not for them to be idly spinning its heels.  This is however the way a UI thread works.  It spends 99% of its time in the message loop, waiting for Windows to tell it to do something.  A button click, a paint request, a keyboard press, that sort of thing.  While it is inside the message loop, it is in fact idle.  A very good time to execute injected code.

Which is what Winforms' Control.Begin/Invoke and WPF's Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke do.  They put a delegate in a queue, the queue is emptied and the delegate targets executed by the message loop.  The WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext and DispatcherSynchronizationContext classes are the synchronization providers that uses them.  Winforms and WPF replace SynchronizationContext.Current with an instance of them.  Which in turn gets used by BGW to raise the events.  Which makes them run on the UI thread.  Which allows you to update the non thread-safe user interface components from a worker thread.

You can probably see where this is heading, a service uses neither.  The default synchronization provider doesn't synchronize anything.  It simply uses a threadpool thread to call the Send or Post callback.  Which is what will happen when you use BGW in a service.  Now there is actually no point at all in having these events.  You might as well let the DoWork handler call the event handling methods directly.  After all, the thread on which DoWork runs is just another threadpool thread as well.

Well, no real harm done, other than making it quite a bit slower.

Answer (score 1):

I've used BackgroundWorker in windows services many times without any ill effect. While its use of SynchronizationContext may be unnecessary, I haven't observed it causing problems or poor performance.